# C++11 compilation errors with std::move and std::make_move_iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, set, move-semantics

Can somebody explain to me why does this fail to compile:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <utility>
#include <set>

template<typename T>
std::unordered_set<T> FailMove(std::set<T> &&set) {
  std::unordered_set<T> response;
  response.insert(std::make_move_iterator(set.begin()),
                  std::make_move_iterator(set.end()));
  return response;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  std::set<int> set{1, 3, 5, 7};

  auto res = FailMove(std::move(set));
  std::cout << res.size() << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

The clang output (command: `clang++ -std=c++11 -otest test.cpp`) is:

```
In file included from test.cpp:1:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iterator:948:14: error: cannot
      cast from lvalue of type 'const value_type' (aka 'const int') to rvalue reference type 'reference' (aka 'int &&'); types are not
      compatible
      return static_cast<reference>(*__i);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/unordered_set:830:34: note: in
      instantiation of member function 'std::__1::move_iterator<std::__1::__tree_const_iterator<int, std::__1::__tree_node<int, void *> *,
      long> >::operator*' requested here
        __table_.__insert_unique(*__first);
                                 ^
test.cpp:10:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::unordered_set<int, std::__1::hash<int>,
      std::__1::equal_to<int>, std::__1::allocator<int> >::insert<std::__1::move_iterator<std::__1::__tree_const_iterator<int,
      std::__1::__tree_node<int, void *> *, long> > >' requested here
  response.insert(std::make_move_iterator(set.begin()),
           ^
test.cpp:18:14: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'FailMove<int>' requested here
  auto res = FailMove(std::move(set));
             ^
1 error generated.
```

gcc output (command: `g++ -std=c++11 -otest test.cpp`):

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iterator:63:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator.h: In instantiation of 'std::move_iterator<_Iterator>::value_type&& std::move_iterator<_Iterator>::operator*() const [with _Iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>; std::move_iterator<_Iterator>::reference = int&&; std::move_iterator<_Iterator>::value_type = int]':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/hashtable_policy.h:647:18:   required from 'void std::__detail::_Insert_base<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::insert(_InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int> >; _Key = int; _Value = int; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>; _ExtractKey = std::__detail::_Identity; _Equal = std::equal_to<int>; _H1 = std::hash<int>; _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing; _Hash = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash; _RehashPolicy = std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy; _Traits = std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, true, true>]'
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unordered_set.h:393:4:   required from 'void std::unordered_set<_Value, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::insert(_InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int> >; _Value = int; _Hash = std::hash<int>; _Pred = std::equal_to<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>]'
test.cpp:10:3:   required from 'std::unordered_set<T> FailMove(std::set<T>&&) [with T = int]'
test.cpp:18:37:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator.h:963:37: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::move_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int> >::reference {aka int&&}' from expression of type 'std::remove_reference<const int&>::type {aka const int}'
       { return std::move(*_M_current); }
```

However this code does compile in both compilers without problems:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>
#include <map>

template<typename K, typename V>
std::unordered_map<K, V> FailMove(std::map<K, V> &&map) {
  std::unordered_map<K, V> response;
  response.insert(std::make_move_iterator(map.begin()),
                  std::make_move_iterator(map.end()));
  return response;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  std::map<int, int> map{{1, 1}, {3, 3}, {5, 5}, {7, 7}};

  auto res = FailMove(std::move(map));
  std::cout << res.size() << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

clang version tested:

```
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

gcc version tested:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: It compiled successfully for me http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3bf16d2a8290b17

Comment: Fails for me in Visual Studio 2013, strangely enough.  error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'const int' to 'int &&'" being one of the slew of errors I get.  Edit:  and your second example compiles fine, as expected.

Comment: @Robinson if you read the error messages, that is exactly the error in clang. Not pretty sure about gcc.

Comment: Are you just curious, or do you actually expect to move values out of the `set`?  I can tell you why it won't work (trying to move objects out of a `std::set`) far easier than why it won't compile: Because `set` will not let you modify its contents while the data is in the container, and a move iterator still operates on data within the container.  Proving that it should lead to a build failure is harder, and would require standard-delving.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short version is `set::begin()` returns a `const_iterator` while `map::begin()` returns an `iterator`.  You cannot move from a `const_iterator`.

The long version is that the "Key" component of associative containers are treated as `const` within the container.  A `set` contains nothing but a Key component.  A `map` contains both a Key component and a Value component.  The values of `set` are Keys.  The values of `map` are `std::pair< const Key, Value >`.

This is because modifying the Key component of a standard container in a way that changes the order of elements breaks the invariants of the container.  This is true even if you intend to shortly discard it, as even traversal, destruction, or anything else can be broken (in theory) by editing Key components!

---

When you move from an iterator `it`, it tries to cast `*it` to `value_type&&`.  For a const iterator, `*it` returns `value_type const&`, and the cast fails.

In the case of `map`, the move will move the Value component, and copy the Key component.

Comment: Looks like `move_iterator::reference` was changed in [LWG 2106](http://wg21.link/lwg2106) from being based on `value_type` to being based on `reference`; the code in the OP compiles with GCC 5.1.

Comment: @T.C. Ah: it compiles, but it "fails to work" in that the purported move iterator doesn't move (unless the value-type has mutable state and a `const&&` move constructor that is).  That does look like "the right thing to do".